# How to make comments on craft CMS?

Tags: craft3, plugins, comments

Нow to create comments on this CMS?
So far, I see only such a way -
to create a separate section and write a module for adding entries to it. But something tells me that I will face a lot of problems while I am implementing my method.
Maybe there is some ready-made and very convenient plugin for this? Free of course))

Answer (score 2):

It's not free, but there is the [Comments](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments/features) plugin.

If you want to go at it yourself, you certainly can use a Comments section (as a structure). That could handle:

- Users vs Guests
- Replies

But there's lots the Comments plugin covers that you'd have to implement yourself:

- Email notifications (replies, original author, admin, subscribed)
- Captchas/spam/banning

If you really want free, I'd look no further than [Disqus](https://disqus.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going the disqus route, there's a plugin available from NYStudio107. https://plugins.craftcms.com/disqus?craft4